# Jython: cannot import name String [from java.util]

Tags: java, string, compiler-errors, maximo, jython-2.7

I'm trying to use a **Jython** automation script in **Maximo 7.6.1.1**:

```
from psdi.iface.router import HTTPHandler
from java.util import HashMap
from java.util import String
handler = HTTPHandler()
map = HashMap()
map.put("URL",url)
map.put("HTTPMETHOD","GET")
responseBytes = handler.invoke(map,None)
response = String(responseBytes,"utf-8")
```

*Source:  [Maximo 76 Scripting Features](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/form/anonymous/api/wiki/02db2a84-fc66-4667-b760-54e495526ec1/page/03ad118c-6040-43dd-bc6d-d7a03510d135/attachment/1004fd2b-1b51-411e-8df0-a8b02ca86272/media/Scritping76Features%20%285%29.pdf) (PDF download)*

---

However, I'm getting an **error** at line 3:

```
ImportError: cannot import name String in <script> at line number 3
```

---

I can isolate the error by deleting everything except line 3:

```
from java.util import String

-------------------------------------------------------------------

ImportError: cannot import name String in <script> at line number 1
```

**Why can't I import `String` from `java.util` into my Jython script?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is [`java.lang.String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html).

There is no `String` in [`java.util`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/package-summary.html).